# How to use key board arrow keys in selectInput of shiny - rstudio

Tags: shiny, rstudio

In the following code how can I use the keyboard arrow keys to go up and down to select categories  from the drop down list and once I hit "enter" I would like to have it selected.

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
mychoices <- c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2")

ui <- fluidPage(
selectInput("campaigns", "Choose campaign(s):", multiple = T, choices = 
mychoices),

)
server <- function(input, output, session) {


}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a basic example that should allow you to play with cursors and see the results.

```
library(shiny)
rm(list = ls())

mychoices <- c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2")

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(4,selectInput("campaigns", "Choose campaign(s):", multiple = T, choices = 
                mychoices)),
  column(8, textOutput("prints"))

)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$prints <- renderText({ 
    if(length(input$campaigns) == 0 ) return()
    input$campaigns
  })
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: This is not what I want. I need to use the arrow keys in the keyboard to go up and down in the list.

Comment: Mmm. Usually you need to click once with the mouse the input box, but then you can use arrow keys (and NewLine) to select. An alternative, if the selectors are numeric, is to use `numericInput`. Why don't you have a look here https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/widget-gallery.html to see which type of input you need? Once you have selected what you need I can help you to implement it in code.